# how to update ListView with Kivy? Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've seen this issue in other threads but I simply can't get any progress with the things that I've found and tried.

I have a Kivy application that saves data in one specific folder and also has the feature to load previous saved data from this folder. I can see a list of this data but my problem is that I can't update the current list to get the new information saved.

I need to rebuild the script to see the new files in the folder.

How could I do this with the current code developed that I have? What I need to add? I will share some code to show what I have.

**python:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import os, sys, os.path


class Screen_Management(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Routes_List_Screen(Screen):
    #path = "/home/pi/Documents/myRoutes"
    path = "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\myRoutes"
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    my_data = ListProperty(dirs)
    list_item = ObjectProperty()


class Race_Setup_Screen(Screen):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("gui.kv")

class guiApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation


guiApp().run()
```

**kv file:**

```
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

Screen_Management:
    id: screen_management
    Race_Setup_Screen:
        name: "race_setup_screen_name"
    Routes_List_Screen:
        name: "route_list_name"
        manager: screen_management


<Race_Setup_Screen>:

    Button:
        text: "ROUTE LIST"
        on_release: app.root.current = "route_list_name"
        # I think I can put a call to a function here that 
        # will update the current file list.

# Screen 6: Route List Screen
<Routes_List_Screen>:
    list_item: data_list_view

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 1
        Button:
            size_hint: [1, .1]
            font_size: 20
            text: 'DATALOGGER'
        ListView:
            id: data_list_view
            size_hint_y: .8
            adapter:
                # Here is the Adapter
                ListAdapter(data=root.my_data,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=False,
                cls=ListItemButton)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: [1, .2]
            Button:
                text: 'BACK'
                on_release: app.root.current = "race_setup_screen_name"
            Button:
                text: 'LOAD'
                on_release: app.root.current = "race_setup_screen_name"
```

I hope to get some help from you guys, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the [on_pre_enter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) event, which is executed before the new screen is displayed, to load the new directories

```
class Routes_List_Screen(Screen):
    #path = "/home/pi/Documents/myRoutes"
    path = "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\myRoutes"
    my_data = ListProperty()
    list_item = ObjectProperty()

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.my_data = os.listdir(Routes_List_Screen.path)
```

Comment: Seems to solve the problem, thanks!!! I will do more tests to see if nothing goes wrong, saludos desde Venezuela!

Comment: @fabianpi Tell me if you have any problems, greetings from Peru. :D